# How to enter a text in a textbox in a webpage with onblur,onfocus and onkeydown attributes using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to automate the process of entering a value in the textbox of a webpage(kind of automating my timesheet). The html code for the text box is as below

```
<input type="text" class="" onblur="return setValue(this);" title="Time";  onfocus="return getValue(this)" onkeydown="return Validate(event);" value="" id="0_0_1">
```

I have to enter the value '9.00' in the textbox. I have used the below code

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('0_0_1').value = '9.00';");
```

I have also used the below code,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="0_0_1"]")).sendKeys("9.00");
```

and also tried with

```
driver.findElement(By.id("0_0_1")).sendKeys("9.00");
```

but the time is not gettting filled in the textbox.Is it due to the onblur, onfocus,onkeydown attributes in the code? Suggestion Please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: There are no errors. But still the data is not entered in the text box. And the program stops at this code.

Comment: Can you try with just entering 9 or any single digit? What is setvalue and getvalue doing?

Comment: If the program stops you should get exception after some time (I'm assuming its not the end of the code).

Comment: @Grasshopper I tried with 9 also.. The value is not entered in the text box. I even tried 'abs'.. Still it is not working. The html code is the code of a webpge and I am not aware of the setvalue and getvalue functions.

Comment: @Guy yes.. this is not the end of the code.. I have also used a button click code at the end.. Neither I get any exception

Comment: your second code contains an error in the xpath formation. but others should work if you don't have issue elsewhere in your project code.

Comment: May I know wat is the error?

Comment: Can we find an element by its Title in Selenium?

Comment: @Vishnu yeah you can By.xpath("//*[@title="Time"]"))

Comment: Replace double quotes with single quotes for attribute value. Your code should be like this:
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='0_0_1']")).sendKeys("9.00");

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the value attribute using `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("0_0_1"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '9.00')", element);
```

Comment: I am getting the exception ' Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null ' when i run the code

Comment: Thanks but still the data cannot be entered automatically

Comment: @Vishnu Any exceptions?

Comment: It is showing unble to find the element.. The problem is ajax is being used and hence the url remains same but the content of the page is changed. Hence the secified id is not found in the url.

Comment: @Vishnu If the `title="Time"` attribute remains you can use it to locate the element `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[title='Time']"));`